# On a led driver how do I reduce the voltage from 91 volts to 32 volts

Tags: voltage-divider

I currently have numerous 50w led spotlights and a few of these led chips have gone faulty and I would like to replace with another 50w chip but they have different voltage requirements. The existing led driver is part of the spotlight and I would like to continue using it for the new led chip. The voltage from the led driver is currently 91 volts and the new led chip requires between 30 and 34 volts. How do I reduce this voltage?

Comment: If your new LEDs are 50 W at 30 V and your old LEDs are 50 W at 90 V. First thing is your current requirements are going to be different, 50 W @ 90 V =  550mA, 50 W at 30V = 1.6A. Can your old LED drivers supply at least 2A? (Rated at 180W @ 90V)

Comment: Connect pin 6 to pin 3. Or maybe 7 to 4. Or then again maybe try 1 to 2. Without partnumbers and links to datasheets this question is a better fit for psychics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Maybe you could find the right chip with the right voltage?

Comment: @Transistor I knew you were going to say that 30 minutes ago.

Comment: Is that 91V with a good LED chip connected and lit, or 91V with nothing or a bad LED connected?

Comment: I'm having trouble with _LED chips_ do you mean the LEDs themselves? If it was me, I'd buy new LED drivers even if it costs more to begin with. With the old drivers, like I said you'll need an extra 130W, lets assume you have 9 spotlights, that puts us at an extra 1.2kW/h. If you have your lights on 2 hours a day 365 days a year that's a wastage of 876 kW, I don't know electricity prices per kW but it can't be cheap. _This is only true if I've figured it out correctly, which I can't guarantee_

Comment: Connected to faulty led chip
What would be advisable to do to obtain correct reading?

Comment: In each spotlight there is a driver.
Cannot find a 50w led chip that runs at the 90 volts

Comment: The chip is 10 leds in rows and 5 rows in one "chip"

Comment: Unfortunately the driver does not have any details printed on it

Comment: LED drivers in that range are usually constant current deviced.  They have a voltage range, and adjust the voltage within that range to keep the current through the LED constant.  If there is no LED connected, the voltage will go upto the maximum the driver is capable of as it tries to "force" the correct current to flow.  The voltage when a good LED is connected is probably lower.  You need to find the voltage range and the current level for your driver.

Comment: Make sure the voltage rating of your new LEDs is within the driver voltage range.  Make damn sure that the current rating of yourLEDs is the same or higher than the current rating of the LEDs.  If the current rating on a constant current supply is higher than the rated current of the LED, then the LED will probably burn out - the bigger the mismatch the sooner the LED will burn out.

Comment: Thank you - will measure the voltage on one of the working spotlights and go from there.

Answer (score -2):

They sell modules at a modest price that will allow you to adjust both the current and voltage to fit your needs. Wattage requirements are important.